# Javascript/HTML: onClick image alert not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've looked all over Stack Overflow and still can't find an answer I'm looking for. I'm very new to JavaScript (not new to Java). I'm trying to make a "page" on my website X out when the image X is clicked.

```
<img name= "pageXSymbol" src="IMAGEURL">
```

And my JavaScript code for this is:

```
$("pageXSymbol").on("click", function() {
    alert("Are you sure you want to delete this page?"));
});
```

I'm not trying to actually delete the "page" yet, I'm just trying to make the alert pop up when clicked. Nothing has been happening when I click the image.

Comment: *"I've looked all over Stack Overflow"* - Seriously..? Fromwhere did you come up with `$("pageXSymbol")` ? A single google search will give plenty of examples to select an element using it's name...

Answer (score 1):

You have to target the name attribute

```
$("[name='pageXSymbol']")
```

Your selector targets the tagName, so `$("pageXSymbol")` would match `<pageXSymbol></pageXSymbol>`

[**jQuery selectors**](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<img name= "pageXSymbol" id = "pageXSymbol" src="IMAGEURL">
```

javascript:

```
$('#pageXSymbol').click(function() {
    alert("Are you sure you want to delete this page?"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `$("pageXSymbol")` -- jQuery trying to access `<pageXSymbol>` HTML element, not `<img name="pageXSymbol">`

To make your code work use should access element via `name` attribite:

```
$("img[name=pageXSymbol]").on("click", function() {
    alert("Are you sure you want to delete this page?"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help...

HTML:

```
<img id="XSymbol" name="pageXSymbol" src="URL">
```

JS:

```
$( "#XSymbol" ).click(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
});
```

Refer to JQuery Click Function.